# django/android - is there anyway to "listen" to json api changes?

Tags: android, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using djangorestframework for my api and I am also creating an Android App, which gets and posts data from the api itself. I was wondering if there is anyway to listen for json data changes from the api. For example, in a chat app, when i send a message(POST into REST api), i want the receiver to receive an android notification when the system finds out that a message was received. Is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could use [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to notify your clients about updates. either embed the update directly in the message - or use it as a trigger to poll your API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your server can not directly connect to the device of the recipient (due to firewalls and mobile networks).
The most popular solution to circumvent this problem is probably [Google Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (now part of firebase).